# NServiceBus IP Address

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, nservicebus

I am new to Nservicebus and have recently started working in it. I am stuck on a point and need input from you guys. I have 2 asp.net core web api projects and I want to use NServicebus to send messages between both of them in some scenarios.

What I have found so far that I can provide name to EndpointConfiguration, what if one of my api is deployed on 1 server and 2nd on another server, in that case how my configuration should be?

I tried to gave url instead of name in EndpointConfiguration but it gave me exception.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NServiceBus endpoints communicate over some messaging infrastructure your system will be using. Endpoint names represent queues messages sent to. Messaging infrastructure is abstracted by what NServiceBus is calling a Transport. You will need to decide on the transport you'd like to use (see the options [here](https://docs.particular.net/transports/)). Once you've decided what transport your solution will use, you could have a look at the samples for that specific transports to have an idea how to set up your endpoints.

For example, if you'll decide to use [Azure Service Bus](https://docs.particular.net/transports/azure-service-bus/) as your transport, you could download and try the [Send/Reply sample](https://docs.particular.net/samples/azure-service-bus-netstandard/send-reply/).

A good starting point could be the tutorials available on the documentation site [here](https://docs.particular.net/get-started/).